# How to run more than one command with Python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, command, popen

I'm trying to run three commands with subprocess.Popen(), i don't know which is the problem.
The commands are running properly on the terminal but not on the code. Here is the code and the output.

```
    str1 = os.path.join(install_path, "components", "esptool_py", "esptool", "esptool.py")
    print(install_path) #/home/laura/esp/esp/idf
    print(str1) #/home/laura/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py
    str_result = "error has occurred, check if the credential in the \"input.config\" are correct"
    
    cmd1 = f"cd {install_path}; . ./export.sh; python3 {str1} flash_id"
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    gui.write_on_output_text("1.0", "checking database for incorrect input on device code")

    out, err = cmd.communicate()
    out_str = str(out.decode("utf-8"))
```

THE OUTPUT:

```
/home/laura/esp/esp-idf
/home/laura/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py
/bin/sh: 22: ./export.sh: [[: not found
```

COMMAND IN TERMINAL THAT WORKS PROPERLY:
cd /home/laura/esp/esp-idf ; . ./export.sh ; python3 /home/laura/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py flash_id`

I don't know why in the terminal works, but in the code not. And i don't know if the error is that is **NOT FINDING THE FILE or THE COMMAND.**

Thank you :)

I already tried many ways to do it.
First i used the command gnome-terminal but it was not correct, because i don't want a new terminal I just want to send these 3 commands.

I know that in the terminal works because the response after send it is good, is what i expected, but in the code is not working, and I'm not sure if it's because Python cannot find the commands on /bin/sh, or if cannot find the file "export.sh".

I have this problem with the 3rd command too, it cannot find the "esptool.py"

Comment: Your `export.sh` will be run by `/bin/sh` not `bash` so it may not contain *"bash-isms"*.

Comment: Hi Laura (I'm assuming that's your name!) and welcome.  It looks like it is executing your script and using 'sh' to run the 'export.sh' but is this a bash-specific script (export.sh I mean)?  If so you might be better to encapsulate all you have in 'cmd1' in a script file with a header specifically saying "#!/bin/bash".

Comment: Another option might be to formulate the command as f"/bin/bash -c 'cd {install_path}; . ./export.sh; python3 {str1} flash_id' " - I'm not able to test these at the moment, but perhaps some ideas will help... :)

Comment: Another option might be `subprocess.Popen(..., executable='/bin/bash')`

Comment: I fix it! I used the option subprocess.Popen(..., executable='/bin/bash')
Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with one of the ideas/resolutions on the comments.

```
subprocess.Popen(..., **executable='/bin/bash'**)
```

Just adding this :) The problem as they said, is that, i was trying to run with 'sh'

Comment: Well done and thank you for sharing the solution back with the community.

Comment: You want to avoid `Popen` always when you can. The simple case of running a command and waiting for it to complete is best served by `subprocess.run` instead, as also suggested in the `Popen` documentation.